# How to configure different web application contexts for one servlet with different mapping

Tags: java, spring, servlets, applicationcontext

First of all I have have generic http servlet which I want to run in specific contexts **depending on URL mapping** (so I switched to HttpRequestHandler implementation). Please consider simplified example. In web.xml I have following configuration:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>local.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>local.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My servlet is implementation of HttpRequestHandler and looks like here:

```
public class TestRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

private Counter counter;

public void setCounter(Counter counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}

@Override
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    writer.write("<h1>" + counter.getName() + ": " + counter.getValue() + "</h1>");
}
}
```

So I want to init both servlet beans (testServlet1 and testServlet2) with different Counters beans and have one root context(applicationContext.xml) for common beans and two **separate** servlet contexts that could extend and override root context (testServlet1-servlet.xml and testServlet2-servlet.xml). So configuration should be something like this:

```
<bean id="counter" class="local.Counter">
    <property name="name" value="CounterA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testServlet1" class="local.TestRequestHandler">
    <property name="counter" ref="counter"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="counter" class="local.Counter">
    <property name="name" value="CounterB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testServlet2" class="local.TestRequestHandler">
    <property name="counter" ref="counter"/>
</bean>
```

Is it possible and how could such configuration be implemented? I thought about DispatcherServlet but don't understand how it could be configured with implementation of HttpRequestHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my task. In few words - We create two DispatcherServlets and each servlet configuration has its **own** context which extends the root context. Here is the configuration:

web.xml - setup for two DispatcherServlets

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml - root context and common beans goes here

```
<bean id="counter" class="local.Counter">
    <property name="name" value="CounterC"/>
</bean>
```

dispatcher1-servlet.xml - overrides implementation of common beans and specific configuration in **own** context

```
<bean id="counter" class="local.Counter">
    <property name="name" value="CounterA"/>
</bean>

<bean name="testServlet" class="local.TestRequestHandler">
    <property name="counter" ref="counter"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/test1">testServlet</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```